# Костомные размеры для видео

Tags: html, css, html5, видео

http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/

Сейчас видео растягивается на 100%, и когда задаешь другое значение оно уменьшается и по бокам появляются отступы. Да, понимаю, что если получится его сжать под свои размеры, то картинка будет не красивая, но это, к сожалению, и нужно.

Нужно на 1920х1080 размеры 1920х830. При большей высоте браузера, например 2160x1440 нужен размер видео 2160x1190. Что бы было на весь экран, но меню было всегда видно.

Ну и нужно все это дело на петличном повторе сделать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего лучше transform scale в голову не приходит.
Но для этого надо знать реальные и желаемые размеры.

Comment: Да, неплохое решение, спасибо большое, не додумался что то до transform

Comment: если есть видео рандомных размеров, но известны размеры окна браузера при адаптивности, то как то это можно через тот же транформ сделать?

Comment: Без скрипта - не знаю.

Comment: со скриптом можете написать, пожалуйста?